# How to do mapping of two sources from different database to one target table in Informatica

Tags: sql, mapping, etl, data-warehouse, informatica

I have two sources from different database(one is from UAT environment and another is from SIT environment).these two sources are loading to single target table in (SIT Environment). will it possible to do this transformation in one mapping?
If yes, the how? If no,then any other way to do this ?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to join the tables?

Answer (score 0):

Read about `Joiner Transformation` and `Union Transformation`. Use the one that will suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement if to join the source tables from different database , you can use a joiner transformation.

You can use an UNION transformation if you want to add data from both the sources, if your source definitions are same.

You can also build 2 seperate pipelines with 2 copies of target definition in the same mapping and use TARGET LOAD FEATURE in informatica.